# How can I disable GitLab custom (pre-recieve) hook without rename/delete hook script file?

Tags: gitlab-ci, githooks

I have custom pre-receive hook on project in GitLab CI.

And I need to disable it sometimes.
To do this, I rename custom hooks directory in my repository.

Are there any simpler way to toggle this hook?